# Syntax error unexpected token Joomla 3.8

Tags: joomla

I have this error

SyntaxError: unexpected token: ':'

When I click to learn more this line of script is highlighted

{"csrf.token":"d071dd89fac83086c3908fa6530e47e3","system.paths":{"root":"","base":""}}

I am really sorry but I do not know enough about this subject to be able to discover the source of this problem and even if I found it I probably would not be able to fix either without some help.

I have had some problems with scripts running on my up to date version of this site 3.8.7,  I have gone back and found the original fresh version of this site install of joomla 3.8.3 on localhost has the same error, so it has been present from the start of this sites development. I do not know if you are able to help and apologise if I am wasting your time

Comment: Please add more detail and a code example.

Comment: might look into a conflict with javascript libraries.  But really hard to say without code or URL.

Comment: Thank you for getting in touch, a url from my website https://mygolfdays.com/golf-courses-in-scotland/aberdeenshire-golf/aboyne-golf-club. This error appears in Firefox and Chrome havent checked the others browsers